# can't move row by row in database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to select the latest row in my items tables in my database and display the title, description along with an image of the item that is stored in a separate folder but the path is stored in the same table. I can display the row but my previous button isn't working, it goes to the very first row. I want it to move one row back each time I click it. Please help. Below is my code

```
<?php
include("scripts/connection.php");
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION["username"])){
header("Location:login.php");
}
$posts = "SELECT ID, Title, Description, PostDate, Image1, Image2, Image3 FROM items Order By PostDate";
$select = mysql_query($posts);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($select);

if (isset($_POST['previous'])){
For($i=1,$i>=0,$i--){
mysql_data_seek ($select, $i);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($select);
$ID ="$row[ID]";
$title = "$row[Title]";
$datetime = "$row[PostDate]";
$image1 = "$row[Image1]";
$image2 = "$row[Image2]";
$image3 = "$row[Image3]";
$description = "$row[Description]";
}
}else{

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){
$ID ="$row[ID]";
$title = "$row[Title]";
$datetime = "$row[PostDate]";
$image1 = "$row[Image1]";
$image2 = "$row[Image2]";
$image3 = "$row[Image3]";
$description = "$row[Description]";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sorting them descending by date:

```
$posts = "SELECT ID, Title, Description, PostDate, Image1, Image2, Image3 FROM items Order By PostDate desc  ";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it still isn't working, when I do that it loads the page with that first row and when I click the previous button it loads the latest post